# How to add extended key usage string when generating a self-signed certificate using openssl

Tags: mac-osx, windows-server-2012, openssl

I'm using openssl on Mac OS X 10.9 to generate a self-signed certificate for Windows Server Remote Desktop Services.

Using the command below I can generate the certificate,

```
   openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myserver.key -out myserver.crt
```

However, I need to add an extended key usage string **Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)** and I can't figure out how to do it in the command above.

I have tried using the openssl option **-extfile** with a file containing this,

```
[= default ]
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
```

However, I get an error that "-extfile option is not found"

Comment: (CLI) openssl config files convinced me it was easier to write code to generate the certificates I wanted. I used golang, but I guess you could use the openssl clib.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While `openssl x509` uses `-extfile`, the command you are using, `openssl req`, needs `-config` to specify the configuration file.

So, you might use a command like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -config cert_config -extensions 'my server exts' -nodes \
            -days 365 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myserver.key -out myserver.crt
```

The usual prompts for the distinguished name bits are defined in the default configuration file (which is probably `/System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf` on OS X), but this file is not processed when you use `-config`, so your configuration file must also include some DN bits. Thus, the above-referenced `cert_config` might look something like this:

```
[ req ]
prompt             = no
distinguished_name = my dn

[ my dn ]
# The bare minimum is probably a commonName
            commonName = secure.example.com
           countryName = XX
          localityName = Fun Land
      organizationName = MyCo LLC LTD INC (d.b.a. OurCo)
organizationalUnitName = SSL Dept.
   stateOrProvinceName = YY
          emailAddress = ssl-admin@example.com
                  name = John Doe
               surname = Doe
             givenName = John
              initials = JXD
           dnQualifier = some

[ my server exts ]
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
# 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 can also be spelled serverAuth:
# extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth

# see x509v3_config for other extensions
```

As indicated in the comment, you can probably leave out most of the DN fields. For HTTPS usage, I think all you need is a CN that matches your hostname.

---

The [Distinguished Name and Attribute Section Format section](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html#DISTINGUISHED_NAME_AND_ATTRIBUTE) of [*req(1)*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html) shows how you could modify the above configuration to prompt for values (and provide default values) if you wanted to generate multiple similar certificates/requests.

If you need other certificate extensions, check
[*x509v3_config(5)*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html) 
for what other bits you can specify in extension sections.

Comment: If you are just generating a CSR with this command line then use -reqexts 'my server exts' to request that the CA later generate a certificate with the server auth enhanced key usage.

Answer (score 10):

With newer OpenSSL versions this all can be done on a single command line without the need to create a configuration file. The option `-addext` was also added to the [`req` command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-req.html)
For a full list of possible values for the extended key usage take a look into the [config manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html).

A full example:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out server.pem -days 7300 -subj '/CN=My Name/C=US/OU=My Unit/O=ACME' -addext "keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, cRLSign, keyCertSign" -addext "extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth"
```